# check for NANs in a list of strings

Tags: python

Is there a quick way to check for NANs in a list of strings? I tried `np.isnan(x)` but get the `TypeError` message `Not implemented for this type`, because `x` in most cases is a `str` type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by NANs in a list of strings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I mean float type NaNs.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to just convert everything in the list to a string:

```
my_list = [str(my_list) for l in my_list]
```

All the `np.nan` will be turned into the string 'nan' and all the strings will stay strings. You can then filter out the 'nan's.

Comment: i think you meant.. `my_list = [str(l) for l in my_list]`. Please correct it if yes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to specifically check for `float('nan')` within a list of strings is to check for float type and then check whether `!=` with itself is truthy (which is only the case for actual `nan` values):

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> isinstance(nan, float)
True
>>> nan != nan
True

def typesafe_isnan(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, float) and obj != obj
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. Can you please explain  what nan != nan is working or what obj != obj is working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if 'NaN' is in a string

```
for item in list:
    if 'NaN' in item:
        print 'NaN in string!'
```

if you want to check if a string is exactly 'NaN'

```
for item in list:
    if 'NaN' == item:
        print 'String is NaN!'
```

If you're not sure of the case of 'NaN'

```
for item in list:
    if 'nan' == item.lower():
        print 'String is NaN!'
```